# Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrease

I have an MVC5 Web api project. I am getting following error after deployment,

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'WebGrease,
>   Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

In My project I have following references,

> System.Web.Mvc - 5.1.0.0
>
> System.Web.Razor - 3.0.0.0
>
> WebGrease - 1.6.5135.21930

Also I have included Following section in my Web.config file,

> ```
> <runtime>
> <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>    <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
>   </dependentAssembly>
> ```

I have tried with following steps but still not working ,

> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
>
> Uninstall-Package WebGrease
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
>
> Update-Package WebGrease

I have referred many links on technical blogs but still getting the same error after deployment.

Can any one help me to find the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was in folders/configs hierarchy in an application. Try to check that binding redirect is in your root web config.

As an example:

```
/AppRoot
Web.config1
/Areas/SomeArea
Web.config2
```

Make sure that you have correct binding redirect in Web.config1.

Hope this helps.